# How to catch only specific type of exception without abort the sequence

Tags: typescript, rxjs

RxJs does not seem to have a variation of `catch()` method which allow to capture only certain type of exception. But many times I found myself in a situation where such operator is needed.

For example, imaging I need to parse each line of a log file and print the parsed message. Some lines of the log file might have been corrupted, but I really don't care and just want to output a "Log message corrupted" for such line and continue to the next line.

If `catch()` did allow us to specify a specific type of error to catch and pass through all other errors, we can then do some thing like pseudo-code below

```
readLogs()
.flatMap parseLog
.catchOnly ParseError, () ->
  'Log message corrupted'
.subscribe (logMessage) ->
  console.log logMessage
```

I was wondering what would be the proper way of RxJs to do that given the current limitation of `catach()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to nest `catch`  in order to prevent an error from terminating the entire chain and you would need to separate the logic for *splitting* and *parsing* lines:

```
import {of, throwError} from 'rxjs'
import {flatMap, map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'



function handleErrors(e) {
    return (e instanceof ParseError) ? 
            of("Log message corrupted") : throwError(e);
}

readLogs().pipe(
  flatMap(splitLines)
  flatMap(line => 
    of(line).pipe(
      map(parseLine), 
      catch(handleErrors)
    )
  )
)
.subscribe(
  parsedLine => console.log(parsedLine),
  e => console.error('Fatal error: ' + e);
);
```

Comment: @pauldaniels, I tried your recipe above and it works. However, I'm confused about the signature of the observable.catch(). According to https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catch.md , it take one or an array of Observables, but in your code, it takes a function which will be passed into the exception.

Is that an undocumented variation of obersvable.catch()?

Comment: There are two variations on it actually the link is for the static method, which does exactly as you say, the version I used is an instance method on Observable.prototype. It is under the file https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md . And it takes either a second observable, or a method accepting an exception returning an observable.

Answer (score -1):

The catch/catchOnly operation is limited in what it can do.

There is no way for a lower link in an Observable chain to tell a higher link to ignore an error.  After *flatMap parseLog* delivers the error, it is done and there is no mechanism for *catchOnly* to tell it to backtrack and ignore that error.

That means the *catchOnly* operation can at best restart the sequence when it sees a particular error.

To achieve the effect you're looking for and keep the sequence going, *flatMap parseLog* should avoid producing the error condition in the first place.  So *parseLog* would need a wrapper to catch the *ParseError* exception and convert it into a valid logMessage.

Answer (score -1):

```
        .catch(error => {
            if (whatever) {
                console.log('I handle this in a cool way')
                return Observable.empty(); // Or an observable that emits whatever you want
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
```

Comment: It will handle one error but after that he observer chain will be "closed". @paulpdaniels example keeps the chain alive.