# Handle error in Subscribe block instead of Http Interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6

I am calling an api through angular service as below

```
this.someservice.save(this.someID, this.payload).subscribe(
  res => { },
  err => { },
  () =>{} );
```

As per some business rule i am throwing a custom exception from API but when i put a debugger inside error block , it does not show any info, instead it jump to interceptor and show there that info.

Is there any way that i can receive this info here instead of interceptor inside

```
err => { debugger; need too get exception here },
```

Reason for this is that i am returning a custom error specific only for this angular component (from where i am calling this service) so need to handle error on this component but this project is allready configured with an HTTP interceptor which is catching all the error at one place.

Comment: you want to use the [`catchError` pipe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJs - How to catch only specific type of exception without abort the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795735/rxjs-how-to-catch-only-specific-type-of-exception-without-abort-the-sequence)

Comment: what to import to use .pipe() as its not available under my codebase

Comment: @Saurabh: What version of RxJS are you using? In RxJS 6+ `pipe` is a method available for `Observable`. You don't have to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can import from 'rxjs/operators' like this:

```
import { pipe, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and then you can use it before subscribe like this:

```
this.someService.save(...args).pipe(catchError( err => console.log(err)).subscribe();
```